# flutter videoPlayerController.addListener() listening multiple times. how can i listen only one time?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**I want to print the video's current playback time in seconds. but it's printing 4 times every second I think.**
here's videoPlayerController.addListener code.

```
await videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value) => {
          videoPlayerController.addListener(
            () {
              log(videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds.toString);
            },
          )
        });
```

**I want this** *videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds* **log will show only once in a second.**

full code

```
void _initVideoPlayer() async {
    var url = await _extractVideoUrl();
    log('url $url');

    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(url);
    await videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value) => {
          videoPlayerController.addListener(
            () {
              log(videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds.toString);
            },
          )
        });

    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: false,
      allowedScreenSleep: false,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      showControls: true,
      startAt: _reStoreLastPosition(),
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your full widget structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The listener will keep listening to the video's position without considering the time.. You can do this instead

```
void _initVideoPlayer() async {
    var url = await _extractVideoUrl();
    log('url $url');
    String lastLoggedTime = "";//<--add a variable here
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(url);
    await videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value) => {
          videoPlayerController.addListener(
            () {
if(lastLoggedTime !=  videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds.toString()){  
lastLoggedTime = videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds.toString(); //<--save it here          
log(videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds.toString());
}
            },
          )
        });

    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: false,
      allowedScreenSleep: false,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      showControls: true,
      startAt: _reStoreLastPosition(),
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    setState(() {});
  }
```